# How to broadcast a list in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, backpropagation

I need to broadcast a list in Python to a larger value. I'm actually working on a backpropogation algorithm without the use of Numpy. I don't have access too it in my limited development environment.

From what I understand when you use Numpy.dot() operation on two arrays, numpy will broadcast one array if it is smaller than the other so they are equal size.

```
   dW = np.dot(dZ, A_prev.T) / m
```

How does Numpy handle broadcasting an array when the two are not divisible? That is, when the modulus of the two arrays does not equal 0?

In my case, I have two lists; len(dZ) is equal too 512 and len(A_prev) is equal too 741. How should I approach broadcasting dZ so it's the same size as A_prev?

What I've tried so far is:

```
dZ = dZ * (len(dZ) + (len(A_prev) % len(dZ)))
```

However, dZ turns out to be a huge number, around 16,000. I'm not sure why.

Comment: IIRC [`np.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) doesn't broadcast, you have to provide suitable shapes yourself.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your devleopment environment, that does not allow the use of numpy?

Comment: I dont understand how you want to multiply 2 vectors of diferent lengths? Could you provide sample inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try these :

suppose that dz is a 3 length array:

```
dz = [4,2,8]
```

and A_prev is 11 item array :

```
A_prev  = [0]*11
```

than to broadcatst dz to the lenght of A_prev , do this:

```
dz = dz* (len(A_prev)//len(dz)) 
dz = dz + dz[:len(A_prev)-len(dz)]
```

and now dz is an 11 item array:

```
[4, 2, 8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this manually and create a new array which has the correct dimensions. The Python motto is explicit is better than implicit after all. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/
Numpy uses a C backend and has many tricks to optimize expressions and therefore you can ignore a lot of technicalities.
Also reusing variable names for data with a different type is confusing and bad practice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).